# Using Imagemagick to batch split png RGBA channels, then recombine as a layered PSD

Tags: command-line, imagemagick, command-line-arguments

I need to separate the RGBA channels of a batch of png images and save the separated channels in a layered PSD. I've been doing this in GIMP, using the decompose colours function and then exporting as PSD, but this is a lot of clicks per image.

I've been trying to automate the process using Imagemagick. After lots of Googling I've made some progress but I'm a bit stuck. Currently I'm using this command:

```
FOR /R %a IN (*.png) DO magick convert "%~a" -channel ALL -separate "%~dpna.jpg"
```

This gives me four jpg images per png (one per colour channel). So far so good. I just need to save the colour channels as layers in psd. One for each of the original images.

I've tried just changing the save format to .psd, like this:

```
FOR /R %a IN (*.png) DO magick convert "%~a" -channel ALL -separate "%~dpna.psd"
```

This gives me a layered PSD file, with only three layers: Alpha, and two other greyscale layers that I *think* are B and G (R missing), but I'm not 100% sure - the original images don't have much colour data in them.

So just to restate - I need to split the RGBA channels of a png, then recombine them as layers in a psd. I need to batch process this over dozens of png images.

Any insight on this would be really appreciated.

Comment: What platform? What version of ImageMagick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think you can do all that you want in ImageMagick. I have not been able to add transparency to the PSD file.

*I am using ImageMagick 6.9.11.34 Q16 on Mac OSX Sierra*

You can process an opaque RGB file and get your layered PSD:

```
convert logo: -transparent white logot.png
convert logot.png \( -clone 0 -channel rgb -separate +channel \) \( -clone 0 -alpha extract \) -type truecolor logot.psd
```

Or you can process RGBA, but A will be just another layer:

```
convert logo: -transparent white logot.png
convert logot.png \( -clone 0 -channel rgba -separate +channel \) -type truecolor logot.psd
```

But to add transparency, you have to do that differently and it does not work for PSD

```
convert logo: -transparent white logot.png
convert logot.png \( -clone 0 -channel rgb -separate +channel -type truecolor \) logot.psd
convert logot.png -alpha extract alpha.png
convert logot.psd alpha.png -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite logot.psd
```

Comment: _Or you can process RGBA, but A will be just another layer _

That's actually exactly what I'm after! - the alpha channel of the images contains data that won't be used for transparency.